# Thread synchronization and signalling

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a specific requirement where I want to have communication between two threads.

I want to implement this multithreaded use case using Java 1.6

Lets assume, we have to secure a region using unmanned drones. The region can be measured in 100km on X axis and 100km on Y axis. Every squire km in this plane can be located using {x,y} co-ordinates.

Drones can have their predefined flying path (it could be random, anywhere in this plain), for example {0,1}{0,2}{0,3}{0,4}{0,5}{0,6}. They have to keep flying from {0,1} to {0,6}. Once drone reached its destination, it should start its journey back, for example from {0,6} to {0,1} and keep flying back and fourth unless stopped.

But one twist - lets say in above flying path drone1 started from {0,1} and reached at {0,2}. The drone1 will keep hovering at {0,2} until another drone releases it. For example drone2 having totally different flying path, but has one or two common positions in path as that of drone1, will instruct drone1 "you can release yourself from this location and keep flying to your path, because I am here to acquire this location".

If you have understood the use case correctly, the problem here is, thread1 which has already acquired the lock on {0,2}, has to wait until thread2 instructs to release it.

How do we do this, how to send a message to another thread and wait until location is empty?

Comment: share with us your attempts to fix the problem.

Comment: I don't know what to do.  As i told in question segment, thread1 has already acquired the lock on location {0,2}. The only thing which is shred between two threads is the location, i cannot find synchronized way to communicate between thread1 and other thread trying to acquire the lock.

Comment: In what language should you write this? Different languages may have different words for the same thing.

Comment: Sorry , i did not specified the language earlier, I want to implement this with Java 1.6 (Also question statement updated)

Comment: So thread/drone is changing its location at it's own pace, but is also forced to change the location when asked to?

Comment: I would start by looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html, take a stab at implementing something with locks, and updating the question with that attempt.

Comment: Thanks, this one is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classical example to use wait() and notify(). Once a drone reaches the destination, it enters a synchronized block in which it waits(). This releases the lock on the synchronized block. As soon as drone 2 arrives, it calls notify(). This wakes up drone 1.

```
public class Square(){

...


public void arriveOnSquare(){
    notify();
    ...
    synchronized(this){
        wait();
    }
    ...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two common approaches to inter-thread signalling:

- a thread executes its routine in a `while(signal)` loop, and exits when the signal turns to `false`
- Through a communication channel-alike object such as `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, the signal sender keeps pushing "tasks" into the queue, and the busy thread keeps pulling from it. As long as there are tasks to do, the busy thread will keep working, and it stops as soon as no more work is left.